# How to relate entities in Symfony 2 and Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony

How can i create a relationship between entities with Symfony 2 and Doctrine? I'm only able to create standalone entities. Maybe someone can help me figure this out using the entity generator? I want to:

- Create two entities: Post and Category. A Post is part of a Category.
- Create a Tag entity: A Post can have many Tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A practical example is covered in Symfony2 docs here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations

To elaborate, taking the first example, you need to create a `OneToMany` relationship between your `Category` object and your `Post` object:

Category.php:

```
<?php

namespace Your\CustomBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="category")
     */
    public $posts;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Post.php

```
<?php

namespace Your\CustomBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="posts")
     */
    public $category;

    /**
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

This should get you started. I've just written this so there might be errors :s

I'm making properties `$posts` and `$category` public here for brevity; <strike>however you'd probably be advised to make these private and add setters/getters to your classes</strike>.

Also note that `$posts` is an array-like Doctrine `ArrayObject` class especially for arrgregating entities, with methods like `$category->posts->add($post)` etc.

For more detail look into association mapping in the Doctrine documentation. You'll probably need to set up a `ManyToMany` relationship between `Posts` and `Tags`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Why do you relate back from Categories to Posts? One relation wouldnt be enough?

Comment: It's just a bi-directional relationship; you don't have to define the `OneToMany` annotation if you didn't need it. But it would be useful if, for example, you wanted to show all posts related to a Category etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't create the relationships with the entity generator itself.

Once the entity classes themselves exist (created either with the entity generator or written by hand), you then edit them to add the relationships.

For example, with your Post having many Tags example

```
namespace Your\Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Your\Bundle\Entity\Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Post
{
  /**
   * @var \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
   *
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="post", cascade={"persist"})
   */
  private $tags;
}
```

See [Doctrine's Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html) for more information about specifying relationships.